# How to use `profile.managed_images_allowed_for_urls` for chrome with selenium?

Tags: selenium

I want to disable the loading of images in chrome, **except for some URL which is needed to allow to load images**.

After I googled and see the code, I found `profile.managed_images_allowed_for_urls` may be usable.

But I don't know how to use the option correctly.

The `chromedriver`'s log show:

```
"prefs": {
               "profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2,
               "profile.managed_images_allowed_for_urls": "http://pic.example.com"
            }
```

My code with python selenium lib:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

prefs = {
    'disk-cache-size': 4096,
    'profile.managed_default_content_settings.images':  2,
    'profile.managed_images_allowed_for_urls': 'http://pic.example.com'
}

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=/tmp/chromedriver.log"])
```

I have tried `managed_images_allowed_for_urls` with value:
`http://pic.example.com`, `pic.example.com`, `*`. All of patterns is not work correctly.

I found some test code from [test1](https://github.com/xdtianyu/android-7.0.0_r1/blob/4bd4cb29853dd0335dc1b04800bc5224f9232e31/external/autotest/client/site_tests/policy_ImagesAllowedForUrls/policy_ImagesAllowedForUrls.py) 
 [test2](https://github.com/webosose/chromium68/blob/a45520cafe8a91488a92df4e0731747da928d2c7/src/chrome/test/data/policy/policy_test_cases.json#L1632), and try to guess some useful info.

I also have tried to find a solution in [code](https://github.com/search?q=managed_images_allowed_for_urls&type=Code), but I cannot find where is handle the pattern. My c++ is poor :(

Comment: there's a comma before the braces at the end of line 5.

Comment: It's the python code. It is ok for python dictionary.
The code can run correctly, but I still can see the picture which is loaded from `pic.example.com`